# Moving Bitmaps in all directions

Tags: android, bitmap, touch-event

What I have is something so when I click and drag my bitmap it will follow your finger, but it really only lets me move it to the right, i can co on a bit of a downward angle to the left as well if I want to but other than that it is nearly impossible to get the thing to move. I need to be able to move it in all Directions though, could you help me? this is my code:

```
@Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
    {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        clear.setARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
        AndroidDudeHitbox.set(AndroidX, AndroidY, AndroidX + AndroidDude.getWidth(), AndroidY + AndroidDude.getHeight());
        canvas.drawRect(AndroidDudeHitbox, clear);
        canvas.drawBitmap(AndroidDude, AndroidX - (AndroidDude.getWidth()/2), AndroidY - (AndroidDude.getHeight()/2), null);
        if (AndroidX > canvas.getWidth() || AndroidX < 0 || AndroidY > canvas.getHeight() || AndroidY < 0) {AndroidX = 30; AndroidY = canvas.getHeight()/2;} 
        invalidate();
    }
@Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
    {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(30);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (AndroidDudeHitbox.contains((int)event.getX(), (int) event.getY()))
        {
            switch (event.getAction())
            {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                AndroidX = (int) event.getX();
                AndroidY = (int) event.getY();
                break;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
```

EDIT :
I just found out that I can NOT move the bitmap directly to right. I can move it directly down and down and to the right. But no were else.

Answer (score 0):

Your checking if the **AndroidDudeHitbox** contains points if its touched, yet your drawing **AndroidDude** on top of it. Either rid the if statement below or draw the hitbox on top of AndroidDude.

`if (AndroidDudeHitbox.contains((int)event.getX(), (int) event.getY())){`

Comment: This doesnt fix my probablem, but I could telll it wouldnt because moving what is being drawn first shouldnt make a difference but my statment is just asking if where Im touching in within the pixels of the hitbox and this already works, I need to know why it will only let me drag him down or down and to the right. But thanks for the respond.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: Don't do a 'sleep' call in your onTouch method. This is asking for trouble.

First, just temporarily, remove the if statement checking AndroidDudeHitbox.contains((int)event.getX(), (int) event.getY()). Just always update AndroidX and AndroidY with event.getX() and event.getY().

And last, and I think most importantly, call '**invalidate()**' after you change the AndroidX and/or AndroidY values in your onTouch. Only a call to 'invalidate()' will cause the onDraw to be called again later.

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
{
    if (true /*AndroidDudeHitbox.contains((int)event.getX(), (int) event.getY())*/)
    {
        switch (event.getAction())
        {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            AndroidX = (int) event.getX();
            AndroidY = (int) event.getY();
            invalidate(); // important!!!
            break;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

If adding a call to 'invalidate()' works, add the 'if' statement again that your removed temporarily and see if everything still works.